# Highlight a DIV on click in page with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am highlighting a div on load.
and passing div id form another page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this will highlight on load
    $("#<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
 });
```

But in this result page i have pagination.
So it is just highlighting the first page divs how can i get to other divs on later pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the id to next page also.

```
Ex www.mysite.com/index.php?page=2&id=thisID
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this will highlight on load
    $("#<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```